# How to handle optional service dependency of service in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've a service called `InformationService`. It optionally depends on `ReleaseService`. If the property `external.releaseservice.url` is set, the `InformationService` shall make a request to it and enrich it's own response with aggregate data.
If however the url is not defined, the response shall simply return a string like `not available` for the fields in question.

What's the spring boot way to achieve this? Inject an `Optional<ReleaseService>` into the `InformationService`? Is there another pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three ways to achieve this.

**@Autowired(required = false)**

This works, but it requires field injection, which is not great for unit tests as is well known.

```java
@Autowired(required = false)
private ReleaseService releaseService;
```

**Java Optional type**

As you said, `Optional` will also do the job and it allows you to stick to constructor injection. This is my suggested approach.

**Spring's ObjectProvider**

There is also an `ObjectProvider` designed specifically for injection points which you can use to achieve this as follows.

```java
public InformationService(ObjectProvider<ReleaseService> releaseServiceProvider) {
    this.releaseService = releaseServiceProvider.getIfAvailable();
}
```

It is more cumbersome and therefore I would avoid it. There is an advantage that allows you to specify a default instance if none is available but I guess that is not what you need.

Comment: What I’m wondering: is this common practice? Or would it be better to provide two informationservice implementations? One with and one without the dependency. Though  that gets tricky with more optional dependencies

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a common practice, but it is relevant enough so that Spring supports it. You could have two different implementations one with and another without the dependency, that is true, but then you would need to play around with `@ConditionalOnProperty` on each of those implementations. If the logic is so different that it makes sense to have two separate implementations, then go for it. If it is not, I would stick with a single Service with the `Optional` dependency. I can update my answer with an example of this `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation if you would like.